# Call a userscript function from within a webpage to close the current tab

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

How can I call a userscript function from within a webpage to close the current tab? Below is a small example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Tampermonkey script (Executed at document start):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Demo
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        *
// @grant none
// @grant window.close
// ==/UserScript==

function tm_function() {
window.close();
}
```

The webpage that is trying to call the userscript function tm_function().

```
<html><body><script>tm_function();</script></body></html>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.
```

Which is the default behavior. However, the userscript has permission to close the tab.

Comment: Add `@grant none` and `window.tm_function = tm_function;`

Comment: @wOxxOm I am trying to close the current tab with the userscript (FYI this was not in the original question). Your solution works in calling the function but the script is run in the window object which prevents it from closing the tab. It needs to be run in the userscript enviromnent.

Comment: Use `unsafeWindow.tm_function`

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error says you can't close a window that wasn't opened by them. Its for security reasons. Scripts only have so much power. They can only close windows that were opened by them. I have tried to do that in the past and there is no solution unfortunately. But you can open tabs using javascript you just can't close ones that weren't opened by the code.